# html input pattern for phone number

Tags: html, input

I need a patter like this [ 081 222 2224 ] with digits limit of 10 ..
This is my try

```
    <form action="" method="post" id="cusCreate" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="tel" name="telphone"  pattern="[0-9]{10}"  title="Ten digits code" required/>    
      <label style="font-size:9px;padding-left:20px"> Eg : 081 222 2224  </label> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbmhjt0r/

Comment: what's the problem, you want a better regex, do you have more constraints?

Comment: You can insert maxlength="10" for digits limit

Comment: i need spaces between the digits like i shown above  **[081 222 2224]**

Comment: pattern="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$"

Comment: @SonuYadav maxlenght is not the problem its work fine with the **pattern {10}** i need spaces between the digits like i shown

Comment: Have a look in this link hope ull get ur answer http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Check my plunker for you answer hope it will work for you

http://plnkr.co/edit/VSxjB0WROhWg0jHXEXQg?p=preview

Comment: @SonuYadav its working fine thank you

Comment: don't use type "tel". Only safari supports it. Nobody uses Safari...

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte if any one browse via mobile tel type by default load the number pad

Comment: If anyone browse the site on an IPHONE, using SAFARI. Anybody that's not on an iphone, and even iphone users using Chrome, won't work. It's your ears man, you do whatever! But using something that is only supported on one of the least popular browsers is not a good practice at all... Even if Chrome was the only browser supporting it I wouldn't recommend it... So when it's only safari... definitely not! But you do you man! It's your code!

Comment: @Nasik, the point is that it'll only work on mobiles. Anyway, it seems like you've made up your mind already. I know I will NEVER make a website that only works in Safari. Or even a site that works on all mobiles but not PCs. If you want something that works only for mobiles, you make a mobile app. Not a website. But again, it's your own project, and you do you!

Comment: Spec: [HTML 5.2 spec section 4.10.5.3.6. The pattern attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-pattern-attribute)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can achieve your result with below changes in your code::

```
<form action="" method="post" id="cusCreate" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="tel" name="telphone" placeholder="888 888 8888" pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}" maxlength="12"  title="Ten digits code" required/>    
      <label style="font-size:9px;padding-left:20px"> Eg : 081 222 2224  </label> 
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>    </form>
```

[For your reference click here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/markup/telerik-takes-cross-platform-mobile-development-to-the-next-level-for-.net-developers-with-latest-telerik-devcraft-release.html#fbid=l8R_j_x1Xqx)

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yt6p3vtm/)

Comment: I think you have not checked in chrome browser, still it's working fine in firefox. good work

Comment: thank you for this solution but user can enter characters like "somthing" inside input

Comment: Thank you, even though "tel" is not a standard bye itself, the pattern works perfectly

Comment: @Gendrith [it is though](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#telephone-state-typetel)

Answer (score 6):

`pattern="[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}"`

This requires the user to put in spaces like this **012 345 6789**. If you want the spaces to be added automatically you should add **javascript** to the `onchange` of the input.
Add `onchange="this.value=addSpaces(this.value);"` to the input and see if it works:

```
function addSpaces(initial){
    initial.replace("/([0-9]{3})/","\1 ");
    initial.replace("/[0-9]{3} ([0-9]{3})/","\1 ");
    return initial;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those from Nigeria we use  phone:

```
new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(080|091|090|070|081)+[0-9]{8}$')])
```

Comment: upvote because devs working with international phone numbers need to remember that patterns can be very different!

Answer (score 0):

Not US but change accordingly:

```
function phoneMask() { 
    var num = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''); 
    $(this).val(
        0 + '(5' + num.substring(2,4) 
        +(num.length>4?')':'') 
        +(num.length>4?' '+num.substring(4,7):'') 
        +(num.length>7?' '+num.substring(7,9):'') 
        +(num.length>9?' '+num.substring(9,11):'') 
    );
}
$('[type="tel"]').keyup(phoneMask);
```